# Bare wire says 120 but drops tall 1 when hooked to outlet

Tags: wiring

120 hot to neutral/hot to ground. Hook it to outlet, hot to neutral reads 1 hot to ground 120. Tried two new outlets. Both do same. Moment connected voltage is lost. Moment wire out, back to normal.

I might also mention two sets of wires. Not sure where other goes. If hook hot to that neutral 90v. Hot to live neutral, 19.

Comment: "If hook hot to that neutral 90v. Hot to live neutral, 19." Are you connecting a hot and a neutral or are you putting a voltmeter across the hot and the neutral? If the former, you are running amps of current through a bad connection and generating enough heat to raise temperature to dangerous levels. This is risking burning a connection and maybe starting a fire.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic sign of a bad connection. The neutral wire likely has a break, is loosely connected, or corroded or charred. You need to find the other end of the wire and inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic back stab problem. It can be with the hot or neutral the moment you apply a load the voltage goes to zero. I find the problem at the last working outlet or first non working outlet in the high 90% range. So if this is the non working outlet go back 1 outlet closer to your service and pull that outlet, it may be on the other side of the wall if a common wall. It could be a broken wire or bad splice at a wire nut but I usually find a bad back stab. If you pull the next outlet and don't see anything but everything now works go back and replace that outlet or at least move to screw terminals as the connection will fail again.

Comment: Really don’t know where to check as it is not on the same feed as the rest of the power in that room. Wires go down, when everything else goes up to attic. It appears to be fed and feeding another location, yet everything else works. To the left is a door, so wires would assume go right unless into cement floor. Checked outlets in adjacent room which would be the only logical continual.  I did replace several outlets including this one. Everything worked when done till a couple days later

Comment: Never assume anything with electrical. Don't want to say it but assuming makes an ass out of you and me if you break the word down. Now it's time to get to work to figure it out. Find the breaker that controls this circuit , turn it off and find any outlets or lights that are now not working that were. Now you will be closer to finding the problem.